# storing length of query sequence as value to the key that is sequence header: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I have written a python script to extract unaligned region from a blast alignment output. I made a dictionary which has a header(sequence identifier) as a key and length of the sequence as its value. The file I am dealing with is a csv file. Here is the piece of my code :

```
my_dict = {} 
for line in fhand: 
    line = line.rstrip() 
    line = line.split(",")    
    if line[0] == "Query":    
        continue   #Skipping the header of our csv file        
    my_dict[line[0]] = int(line[2]) #Storing the sequence identifier as key and the length of sequence as its value.
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pf_extract_mapper.py", line 31, in <module>
    my_dict[line[0]] = int(line[2]) #Storing the sequence identifier as key and the length of sequence as its value.
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sample file I am working on:

```
Query,Hit ID,Query_length,Hit Def,E-Value,query_start,query_end,sbjct_start,sbjct_end
Seq1,seq11111,100,control1,2e-21,10,35,15,31
Seq1,seq22222,100,control2,34e-34,25,40,27,38
Seq1,seq33333,100,control3,25e-27,58,84,54,80
```

Comment: The traceback in your question is incomplete: it omits the exception and its message.

Comment: Are there any blank lines in your data file, or lines with less than 3 elements?

Comment: @DanielRoseman There is no blank line. Actual result file is too big to work with.  But when I ran the program it gave the same Index Error on it too.

Comment: @dsh The complete traceback was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pf_extract_mapper.py", line 31, in <module>
    my_dict[line[0]] = int(line[2]) #Storing the sequence identifier as key and the length of sequence as its value.
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @bioinfo_is_fab FYI you can edit your question to add that information.

Comment: @bioinfo_is_fab The `IndexError` means that either `line[0]` or `line[2]` (since both are on the same line) has an index (the `0` or the `2`, respectively) that is larger than the length of the list. Put some print statements in your loop and see what the line is when it has that error. It isn't in the data you posted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {}

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f, None)
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(',')
        d[line[0]] = int(line[2])


pp(d)

{'Seq1': 100}
```

Comment: In Sample file I have used single sequence, actually in blast a single sequence aligns with multiple subject sequence at different locations. I want key as "Seq1" and value as "100". Thanks.

Comment: @bioinfo_is_fab no problem, take a look.

Comment: Thanks @LetzerWille . But it is showing error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Pf_extract_mapper.py", line 23, in <module>
with open('Testcsv', 'r', newline ='') as f:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @bioinfo_is_fab newline  option can be removed.  I will remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)